# Hijack new call

Tags: typescript

I've got a class in TypeScript, which is fine. I'd like to intercept calls to `new T(...)` so that instead of calling the default machinery instead returns the value from an arbitrary function call (which has a different return type that is completely different to `T`).

I tried something like `new() : OtherT { return func(); }`, which TS accepts without error but when compiling `new T()` still insists that the return is of type `T`.

How can I convince TypeScript to substitute my own function for `new T()`? I could really use a solution that I can place on a base class of `T` rather than `T` itself.

Comment: You want to call `new T()` and get something other than a `T`? I think you're missing the point of Typescript.

Comment: @JLRishe: T's sole purpose is to be converted into a more useful representation, and having `new T()` automatically convert it (since I only require a very narrow subset of T's original semantics) is just more intuitive.

Comment: Ok, but why do you need to use `new` in that case? Can't you just use a factory method? Having `new T()` return something that is not a `T` just runs counter to the whole idea of static typing that TypeScript is trying so hard to preserve.

Comment: @JLRishe factory methods would be more readable too... no surprises to someone who hasn't seen the inner workings of the class.

Comment: @JLRishe: Creating a `T` is what's going on semantically, it's just that there's a bunch of gunk going on in the middle about instance reuse and crap like that.

Comment: @Puppy In that case, why are you trying to change the return type? Can't you just return the `T` after all that gunk has happened?

Comment: @JLRishe: No, I can't. I'm trying to pass the really-a-T-but-technically-not to another function which takes the technically-not and does the gunk itself.

Comment: @Puppy Well, I'm afraid I have no idea what you are trying to describe. I presume you're familiar with the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? That's what this is. You've asked us how to do Y, and very gradually given us vague hints about what X is. We're pretty sure there is no way to do Y, so could you please _show_ us how you intend to use this capability rather than just asking how to make it happen?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I convince TypeScript to substitute my own function for new T()

This is considered *very bad* practice. If you call `new` on a function you expect it to return something that has the `constructor` property correctly setup to point to that function.

This is why TypeScript *classes* enforce that being called with `new` they will return an instance of that *class*.

However if you want a *factory function*, or create type definitions for existing *bad* JS libraries TypeScript will allow you to do that e.g.:

```
interface A {
    foo: number;
}
interface B {
    foo: string;
}

var OldLib: {
    new (): A;
    new (str:string): B;
}


var a = new OldLib(); 
a.foo = 123;               // Is a string

var b = new OldLib('something');
b.foo = '123';             // Is a number
```

Comment: But can you derive from OldLib and get the same effect?